# Returning a value from direct channel flow and proceeding with async flow in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following integration configuration in my web app:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow giraFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            MessageChannels.direct("gira.input"))
            .split()
            .transform(transformer)
            .handle(parserService)
            .channel(routerChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
MessageChannel routerChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.queue("routerChannel", 10)
            .get();
}


@Bean
IntegrationFlow routerChannelFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            routerChannel())
            .route(p -> p.getKind().name(),
                    m -> m.suffix("Channel")
                            .channelMapping(TaskKind.CREATE.name(), "create")
                            .channelMapping(TaskKind.RELOAD.name(), "reload")
            .get();
}
```

and a gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface GW {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "gira.input")
    Task gira(Collection<Request> messages);

}
```

and a `parserService`

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ParserService {

    public Task handle(IssueTrackerTask task) {
        log.info("Parser service handling task {}", task);
        return task;
    }
}
```

I call the gateway method from Spring MVC controller and I want it to return me a `Task` object that the `parserService` returns in it's body method. The important thing is that I want controller to be blocked until it gets the value from the `parserService`. After it gets this value, I want my integration flow to proceed asynchronously with the `routerChannelFlow`, so that web controller method would return as fast as possible, and all heavy operations in the `routerChannelFlow` would be done without blocking controller.

Here's a part of the controller that has this gateway method call:

```
...
Task gira = gw.gira(messages);
log.info("Result {}", gira);
...
```

The problem is that `log.info` is never reached and `gira()` gateway is blocked forever.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

P.S. The `parserService` is actually not needed in my app, this is just what I thought would help me to define a return value for my gateway, but it actually did not help:(

***UPDATE***

So here's what I got after Gary Russell's comment:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(10);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return pool;
}

@Bean
MessageChannel routerChannel() {
    return MessageChannels
            .publishSubscribe("routerChannel", executor())
            .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow routerChannelFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(routerChannel())
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                 .subscribe(f -> f
                         .bridge(null))
                 .subscribe(process()))
            .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow process() {
    return f ->
            f.<IssueTrackerTask, String>route(p -> p.getKind().name(),
                    m -> m.suffix("Channel")
                            .channelMapping(TaskKind.CREATE.name(), "create")
                            .channelMapping(TaskKind.RELOAD.name(), "reload")

}
```

And when I try to use this pipeline, I get the following error `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:development:9000.dummy'`. It's definitely a misconfiguration issue, but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

***UPDATE***

Changed `channel("dummy")` to `bridge(null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is downstream of the `create` and `reload` channels?

What do you do with the `Task` result in the controller (aside from logging it)?

If you don't need a result, change the gateway return to void and add an executor channel downstream of the gateway.

If you want the `Task` object returned, you need the `routerChannel` to be a publish/subscribe channel with an executor and two subscribers - a bridge to nowhere (input channel and no output channel) which will return the `Task` to the gateway, and the router, which will route the Task on a separate thread; the downstream flows from the router must not return a result (the gateway will have long-before stopped waiting for a result).

Instead of adding an executor to `routerChannel`, you could make the two router channels executor channels instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I update the answer with what I got, still struggling to get the right configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your last solution is almost there, you just don't need to use `.channel("dummy")`, but just `.bridge(null)` in that first subflow subscriber for the `.publishSubscribeChannel()`.

What you need there is just to send message back to the gateway's `replyChannel`, which is `TemporaryReplyChannel` in message headers.

The `BridgeHandler` is the best way do "nothing" but just send message to the appropriate `replyChannel` from headers.

Also consider to add `executor` to the channel after `.split()` if your `.transform()` and `.hanlde()` logic is enough heavy.

Comment: One more question stays though: you are suggesting to add another `executor` after `split()`, but what is it going to solve? Controller is still blocked until it gets an answer from the gateway, so it will be blocked either way. Are there any benefits of using `executor`?

Comment: With that the items after splitting will be processed in parallel . Without - one by one.

Comment: Artem, awesome, got it, thanks. You and Russel are doing a VERY good job here in StackOverflow answering my questions regarding integration. Thank you again!